# Is it possible to virtually test Android application on different hardware?

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I am looking for a way (maybe impossible) to test my PhoneGap Android application on different phones / hardware. As I am able to obviously test it only on my phone, but some people are reporting that my app doesn't work / crashes / explodes on their phone. Is there any way how can I test my app on different phones without buying actual device ? Maybe virtually like running Android in an emulator or somehow ? 
It is kind of frustrating knowing that the app works perfectly, but some people are not able to even start it...

EDIT: I am certainly testing the app in Android emulator, but that only helps to test on different Android versions. But I am looking for a way how to test in on different phones without actually buying it - if it is possible ?

Comment: I think I'm misinterpreting something: are you unaware of the android emulator that google distributes with the android sdk? http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a company called DeviceAnywhere: http://www.deviceanywhere.com/ that seems to be doing that.

But it may cost you. If you don't want to buy all those devices, somebody else will have to. Plus they have to build the infrastructure to support remote access. Does not sound like something you would get for free.

Answer (score 0):

You can run it through the emulator that is provided with the Android development kit through Eclipse. But this will only help test the code on different versions of Android not necessarily on the different hardware so if it is really a hardware problem this will not help but if it is related to the different versions of android this should help you find the problem.

Here is information on the emulator and how to use it: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-eclipse.html#RunningOnEmulatorEclipse

Comment: Corey, thanks for answer, but I am already testing the app in Android emulator with different versions. But I am looking for a way (probably impossible, but maybe I am missing something) how to virtually test my app on different phones.

Comment: @Frodik: While I could be wrong, I don't believe it is possible to test on different hardware without physically having the hardware as the only thing an emulator can test is the software that each phone runs. To test the hardware you need the actual hardware aka the phone. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Like DeviceAnywhere, there is another company that will let you test your application on multiple hardware devices. It https://appthwack.com/  . They do have 100 mins of free plan to test out, so go ahead and try this out.